# how to Post values from one form to another form?

Tags: html

**parent.html**

```
<HTML>
<form name="form" method="post" action="child2.html">
<input type="text" value="" name="text2" id="pdetails2">
<input type=submit name="submit" value="submit"></form>
</html>
```

**child2.html**

```
<HTML>
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" value="" name="text3" id="pdetails3">
</form><html>
```

here if i give any value in parent form text box once i click on submit button i need that text box valu in child2 form textbox what can i do?

Comment: You can't with HTML only, and you can't access POST with JavaScript only I believe. Are you using a server side language at all?

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept some answers on some of your other questions.  You'll get a better response on newer questions, and you'll get some reputation.

Comment: If KoolKabin answer is working for you please Accept it by clicking the "V" icon to the left of it..

Answer (score 2):

For your specific solution: you can try it using javascript.

1.) Change the parent.html 's form's method to get instead of post i.e

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="child2.html">
```

2.) In child2.html add the following javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function $_GET(q,s) { 
        s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
        var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
        return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
    } 
</script>
```

3.) use $_GET('var1'); to get the value: e.g in ur textbox:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="text3" id="pdetails3">
<script>document.getElementById('pdetails3').value = $_GET('pdetails2');</script>
```

Comment: sorry i cont understand here what is the value of "var1" ?